# Invertible Hasse-Witt for non-ordinary curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, characteristic-p, arithmetic-geometry

Assume that $S$ is a smooth curve of over a field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$ and $f\colon X\to S$ is a relative curve over $S$ (i.e., the fibers are curves).  It is well-known that when all the fibers are ordinary curves, the Hasse-Witt map $h\colon F^{*}(R^{n}f_{*}(O_{X}))\to R^{n}f_{*}(O_{X})$ is an isomorphism, where $F$ is the Frobenius morphism of $S$ (this result is due to Katz, *Slope filtrations of F-crystals,* in Asterisque '63).

Now, are there cases where the fibers are not ordinary curves but Hasse-Witt map is an isomorphism? Generally, are there reasonable conditions (of course, I mean besides ordinariness!) under which the Hasse-Witt map becomes an isomorphism?

Comment: I presume $n=1$. Do you want examples in higher dimensions? Then there is a general definition of "ordinariness" for varieties over a field of characteristic $p$. Except for the local constancy of the direct images in families, it is pretty much related to the condition you require. See, for example, Part III of my *Cohomologie cristalline*, un survol, Expositiones Math. (1998). 